# C# WinForms User Management

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm working on my first C# program and so far have sorted the database connection, users table, adding new users, login with salt hashed password etc. but am now stuck on how to manage the users.

My Users table has:

- ID (int)
- Name (nvarchar)
- UserName (nvarchar)
- Password (nvarchar - this is the salted hash)
- Administrator (bit)

I want to create a form that manages the users, but don't have a clue of how to lay this out and create the optimum UI.

The form should only be accessible when the current logged in user is an Administrator, but that is easy to sort out so I am not worried about implementing that.

If someone can give me ideas, or even provide example form views of how they have laid out their user management it would be very helpful.

Comment: got a feeling this will get closed as it's a bit too vague and too subjective. + the question is not really code specific

Comment: @whytheq - I know it isn't code specific but once someone suggests a design then it will become code specific as I will need some help getting it coded.

Comment: @TigOldBitties - ListView sounds like something I should be using, but then the question is if someone selects one user to update, should another form come up with the option of changing the details or can the ListView somehow manage all that?

Comment: DataGridViews are pretty powerful - you can see the whole database table and then edit any of the info and then write changes back to the db

Comment: @hshah it can if you handle it. My point is that you should design your UI first then find the technical solution. In the real world that is how it happens. Real projects are usually design driven as far as the UI is concerned.

Comment: @whytheq - DataGridViews also look like something I could use, but what I'm worried about is how it would look to the user who is managing existing users.

Comment: @TigOldBitties - Part of my question is actually the design, because I have no clue how I would design the form.  I was hoping for some ideas from the people on here so I can plan what I want to achieve before I actually start coding.  Both you and whytheq have already pointed me towards ListView and DataGridView which I am looking into now.

Comment: @hshah that is because you are technically driven. Ask a website designer or a designer in general that question and he will draw you a nice mock-up for which YOU will have to find the technical sollution.

Comment: @TigOldBitties - That makes sense.  At the moment I am the one designing and creating this, so will ask around to see if someone else can help :)

Comment: @hshah - this is a **coding** question & answer site

Comment: @hshah [Here's an example](http://i.imgur.com/thwjP.png) (from a LightSwitch app).

Comment: @Nacereddine - Thank you.  That is the sort of thing I was hoping for.

Comment: @whytheq - Apologies.  Is there a way I can close this question myself?

Comment: @hshah either I post it as an answer and you accept it or you could delete this question (dunno if you need more rep for that).

Comment: @Nacereddine - can you please post it as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example (Administration of a LightSwitch app):

[image: LightSwitch app]